# which is better for stability between the delta and rectangular wing designs?

Tags: wing

building a minuscule version of an airplane and need to know between delta and rectangular designs which would be better. I don't need any other designs, just delta and rectangular. Tailless. Which adds more lateral stability

Comment: Tail-less?  Would make a difference.

Comment: Not enough information

Answer (score 3):

In an aircraft with no horizontal stabilizer, it's much easier to create a design with adequate pitch stability if the design has a delta wing than if the design has a rectangular wing.  If the design also has no vertical stabilizer, the advantage of a delta wing over a rectangular wing is even stronger.

If you go for a rectangular wing in either of these cases, you'll find that the CG position is *extremely* critical.

[Here's one website with lots of images of tail-less hang gliders](https://www.delta-club-82.com/bible/hang-glider-bible.php), including early "Rogallo" designs which were simple delta wings.

Your question has been modified to say that you are interested in lateral stability-- an aircraft's tendency to resist rolling away from wings-level.  Delta wings and swept wings contribute a dihedral-like effect that contributes to lateral stability even if the wing has no actual dihedral.  If you want to create lateral stability with a rectangular wing, you'll have to give the wing actual dihedral, or you'll have to mount it well above the CG.

Comment: (Of course, the hang-gliding paradigm opens up the "pendulum stability" can of worms again... )